# Excel VBA Advanced Filter Bug

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I'm trying to resolve an issue when running VBA code to automate the advanced filter function.

Context: I'm running analysis of payments between different customers.

I have the table below where customers have made payments to another customer number. In column F is the customer ID's that represent the customers I want to keep in the table.

[initial table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPgFf.png)

If I use the advanced filter function I get the following table below, which is correct.

[advanced filter table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv4HI.png)

However, when I use the following code:

```
Sub advanced_filter_2()

Dim rgData As Range, rgCriteria As Range, rgOutput As Range
   
    Set rgData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rgCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").CurrentRegion
    Set rgOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    
    rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutput

End Sub
```

I get the following result. Notice that while the customer ID's have been correctly filtered in columns B and D. Column C seems to have copied the data from column A.

[macro result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Ehm.png)

I was wondering how I can change the code above to correct this error?

Comment: In your screenshot it appears you have two identical column headers.  Also, although it does not appear to be the case in Excel 365, I believe in earlier versions you needed to activate the destination worksheet if it was different from the data / criteria range worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

### Advanced Filter (2 Worksheets)

- One of the conditions for data to 'deserve' to be called a table is that it needs to have unique headers. For example, if you do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your source range (to convert it to a table), Excel will, without even 'blinking', rename the critical `C` column header to `Customer Name2`. If you do the same but select the `2` and color it white, it won't be visible (don't forget to do it also in the destination).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub advanced_filter_2()

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim rgData As Range: Set rgData = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rgCriteria As Range: Set rgCriteria = sws.Range("F1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' The following doesn't work for me. It copies only the first column.
    ' A rule of thumb is, whenever it is possible, to reference a complete range,
    ' i.e. don't allow Excel to decide.
    'Dim rgOutPut As Range: Set rgOutPut = dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' This will work if you don't carelessly remove a header without
    ' removing the data below.
    ' If you need this comfort, use the bullet-proof solution.
    Dim rgOutPut As Range: Set rgOutPut = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1)
    
    ' The Bullet-Proof Solution
'    Dim rgOutPut As Range: Set rgOutPut = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
'    If rgOutPut.Rows.Count > 1 Then
'        rgOutPut.Resize(rgOutPut.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Clear
'        Set rgOutPut = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
'    End If
    
    rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutPut

End Sub
```